# Eclipse Indigo - Unknown HTTP response code when trying to add site to update sites list

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add the emacs plus plugin at:

http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site

I have added the referenced URL via help/install_new_software/add

However, the response seems to timeout, and I get the following error message:

```
HHTP Server Uknown HTTP Response Code (302):http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site/site.xml
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException

HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (302):http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site/site.xml
HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (302):http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site/site.xml
General connection error with response code=302
```

This might be because the referenced URL for some reason is returning a 302, but I have checked that it returns 200 using:

http://www.axandra.com/free-online-seo-tool/status-code.php

I'm not 100% certain that this result is definite.

The URL:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Problem-reading-eclipseUpdate-repository/td-p/437888

Describes a similar problem, and refers to directing Eclipse at the URL pointed to by the 302 response, but I can not find this as the URL provided returns a 200 response (I think).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can install Emacs+ from both `Eclipse Markplace` and adding its repository(`http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site`) by hand.

It looks like your network is unstable.

Comment: Any idea how to further diagnose the issue?

Comment: Response code is returned by server, so it mostly looks like a fault on server side. If you have knowledge of plug-in development, you could try to debug [RepositoryTransport class](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf/src/org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/transport/ecf/RepositoryTransport.java).

Answer (score 0):

Note that (as Kane points out), the Emacs+ URL is http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/update-site

In your url above, you left off the update-site part of the path.